# Why is there transparent area around my svg?

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I made an svg image for on my site. When I use it though it looks like this:
[image: image of svg image with transparent background]
There is alot of transparent area around it where I would say it could expand.
There doesn't seem to be any transparent area in the svg image itself.
When I use a png it works fine, just with the svg it creates this blank area.
I just gave the image a red background to see where the image actually is.

This is my css:

```css
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

#logo directs to the `<img>` in my html:

```html
<img src="Sources/FruityJuice Logo.svg" alt="FruityJuiceLogo" id="logo">
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: It may be that the SVG file actually has that size and has "transparent" as it's background, you can try opening it in a photo editor and see if the checkered background appear, if so, you can just crop it to fix your problem.

Comment: What is the markup of FruityJuice Logo.svg

Comment: Dirk, we hebben de **inhoud** van Logo.svg nodig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Adobe Illustrator I cropped the file to the logo like Yong Pin said and that seems to have fixed it.